# Rails: security implications of whitelisting table tags in Rails' sanitizer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, ruby-on-rails-5, sanitize

I see that Rails doesn't whitelist table tags by default for its sanitizer. Is there any particular security reason for this? I can't think of any, but I'm using CKEditor to allow user input of HTML tags, and I'd like them to use tables if they want (so long as there isn't some sort of risk that I'm unaware of). This is my first application where I'm allowing users to set HTML tags, so while I can't find any reason *not* to, I'm still a bit anxious about it.

In a [Rails GitHub issue](https://github.com/rails/rails-html-sanitizer/issues/50), there was discussion about using Loofah's newer list, but the Rails devs decided that they would continue to use the whitelist from Rails 4.1, but there wasn't a clear answer on if there was a security risk with table tags.

BTW, to save people time in figuring out which tags are whitelisted in their version of Rails (which is surprisingly difficult to find), you can go to console (this is for Rails 5.1.4):

```
Rails::Html::Sanitizer.white_list_sanitizer.allowed_tags
=> #<Set: {"strong", "em", "b", "i", "p", "code", "pre", "tt", "samp", 
"kbd", "var", "sub", "sup", "dfn", "cite", "big", "small", "address", "hr", 
"br", "div", "span", "h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "h6", "ul", "ol", "li", 
"dl", "dt", "dd", "abbr", "acronym", "a", "img", "blockquote", "del", "ins"}>

Rails::Html::Sanitizer.white_list_sanitizer.allowed_attributes
=> #<Set: {"href", "src", "width", "height", "alt", "cite", "datetime", 
"title", "class", "name", "xml:lang", "abbr"}>
```